# Changes to firearms based on gasoline

Tags: magic, firearms, guns

I got a little question: how would it effect firearms if they would not be based on gunpowder but on gasoline like flammable liquid?
What I think would happen:
-because the liquid would need to be a mist to be able to explode and this would not be really storable in a shell so guns themselves would need a ignition chamber, a nozzle to spray the liquid in the chamber, a inbuilt tank to store the liquid and a mechanism to pump the liquid. Because they need all of this they would become bigger and therefor heavier and therefor less suitable for infantry

-because they have all those extra mechanisms they would have a low fire rate even in modern times and increase the cost of maintenance

-gasoline is way weaker then gunpowder so the shots themselves would not be that strong and could potential even be blocker by a steel armor or shield

Do you guys have any more ideas of things that would change or think that I got something wrong?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: (1) Modern (= after 1900) firearms do not use the kind of gunpowder invented by the Chinese 1200 years ago. (2) Gasoline was invented about a thousand years after gunpowder. That is, to make gasoline one needs technology very very much more advanced than what one needs to make gunpowder. (No, one cannot simply boil petroleum and obtain gasoline. It is much more complicated than that and involves advanced organic chemistry.) When gasoline was invented they already had modern explosives and "smokeless powder" propellants, such as cordite (English) and Poudre B (French).

Comment: @AlexP thank you for this comment but this is not really getting the point of my question: I am interested in how a gun would need to be modified in order to work on gasoline or gasoline like liquid.
A scenario could be a (perhaps modern) fantasy setting in which solid propellants are not available. 
I'm sorry if I didn't bring this across this way and can change the question if there is a better formulation.

Comment: To burn gasoline you need an oxidizer. Where does the oxidizer come from? (Gunpower and other propellants work because they contain both the fuel and the oxidizer. Gasoline needs about 15 times its weight of air to burn; for example, to burn 1 gram of gasoline you need 15 grams of air, which would be about 15 liters or 4 US gallons.)

Comment: @AlexP much lesser in an atmosphere richer in oxygen and a lot less volume if you compress it (so not necessary a clear cut it cannot work in any conditions). Besides, ignition for things under pressure is easier - you are half-way to the activation energy of the reaction by applying pressure alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work as simply as you describe, because you need an oxidizer (and enough of it) for the gasoline to burn.

Now there is one way to get it to sort of work.  It's a fairly well known phenomenon among air gun users, called dieseling.  Some kinds of air guns are cocked by compressing a spring.  When the trigger is pulled, the spring is released, and compresses the air in front of it, pushing the pellet out the barrel. Now as we know from basic physics, compressing a gas also heats it.  If there is some lubricant between the pellet and the jet of hot air, it may ignite, creating even more pressure, and thus shooting the pellet faster. This is exactly the same principle used in diesel engines. See e.g. https://airgunplanet.com/what-is-airgun-dieseling-and-how-dangerous-is-it-really/

So you could perhaps design a gun that works off this principle.  However, you'd have to have some way to compress the air (for instance by the user pumping it), a mechanism to inject just the right amount of fuel per shot, and perhaps a spark plug to make sure it ignites.  So your gasoline gun is going to start out being rather complicated, high-maintenance, and fault prone, and probably too heavy for a personal/infantry weapon.

So let's re-think this a bit.  Your gasoline (or diesel) gun is basically the same as a one cylinder gasoline engine.  You need a piston to compress the air-fuel mixture, and valves to direct the combustion gasses behind the projectile.  So you add another cylinder which is nothing more than a gasoline engine.  This provides power to keep the whole thing turning.  Add a mechanism to feed projectiles to the firing cylinder, and you have a gasoline-powered machine gun.

Answer (score 6):

Gasoline would not work well as a propellant, because its tendency is to burn rather than explode. (They're not called internal *explosion* engines, after all.) In technical terms, this means that the shock front of the combustion - the dividing line between "burned" and "not burned" - moves slower than the speed of sound.

You can see this for yourself by looking at movie explosions vs. real life explosions. In the movies, what you mainly see is burning gasoline, which produces very dramatic globes of golden flame that visibly blossom and spread. In real life, there's very little flame, and the shockwave of an explosion travels faster than you can easily see.

Mechanically, this translates into lower *brisance*, or peak pressure. This is an important measure of how well a propellant propels because it measures how much energy you can *quickly* impart onto a projectile. It's no good having a lot of potential energy if it takes a long time to be expressed, or if your projectile has already left the barrel (leaving the gasses free to expand behind it). So while gasoline is a great fuel for things that need to move predictably over time, like engines and turbines, it's not great for applications that need a lot of force *right now*.

I suspect that an air gun would be your best bet. Weapons like the late-18th-century [Girardoni rifle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girardoni_air_rifle) were deadly, highly accurate, and had few of the drawbacks of conventional black powder guns (such as smoke and vulnerability to dampness). Its drawback, and the reason it was eventually passed over, was the insane amount of pumping needed to refill its air reservoirs, and the difficulty in manufacturing them, limited the number of shots a soldier could bring to the front. A small, man-portable gas compressor could allow company- or squad-level resupply right on the front line, giving you great longevity.

Comment: But the propellants used in guns burn rather than exploding.  The burn rate of gunpowder has to be matched to barrel length: using fast-burning pistol powder in a rifle can wreck it.  Indeed, I recall at least one mystery novel where the murder was carried out by replacing the powder in a shotgun shell with a high explosive.

Answer (score 1):

Gasoline actually has some of the highest energy densities that can be achieved with modern technique. A gun works by creating a small directed explosion that propels a projectile with rapidly expanding gasses. If an oxidizer is added to the fuel to create the desired amount of explosive sensitivity and ratio of oxidizer/fuel one can achieve the explosive mixture without the need to modify the guns nor the bullets too much at all, it just depends on whether or not your society has discovered this.

Having said that, otherwise using a non-oxidized liquid propellant for your gun would probably only result in some burns on the hand of the would be shooter when burning liquid inevitably leaks all over his hand. Maybe your society is more advanced on the area of incendiary devices if they aren't adept in using oxidizers for whatever reason. It would change the face of battles completely in your setting.

Answer (score 0):

## Flamethrowers

[image]

If all you have is gasoline, then your most practical weapon will be a flamethrower. You don’t have to worry about exploding the stuff, or projectiles. Just use a gas-powered compressor to fill up a tank of propellant, attach a tank of gas, stick a lighter in front, and go to town. Ideally, thicken the gasoline into a napalm like substance.

Unlike the cheap, gas-based flamethrowers, a liquid flamethrower boasts superior range, devastating effects on target, and completely ignoring any infantry armor. The WWII era M1A1 flamethrower was man portable, effective to 45 meters, and worked very well against armored pillboxes and fortifications.

The main effect this would have on warfare is hard to predict. Historically speaking, even experts struggle to fully predict the effects of new weapons in combat (see WW1). One thing is for sure, it’s going to be very unpleasant. Napalm burns are horrific.

Answer (score 0):

It common in spring piston air guns for the air between the piston and the projectile to briefly become very hot during firing.

Hot enough, in fact to ignite fuel, such as gasoline, mixed into that air.

To modify a spring piston air gun to use gasoline, several changes would be needed.

First, a thicker walled barrel and firing chamber, to not be damaged by the firearm-like high pressure.

Second, metal piston rings instead of the typical rubber or plastic seal.

Third, a fresh air intake, since normal springer guns have nothing to ensure air flow (scavenging).

Fourth, a carburetor or fuel injector.

Sixth, a sparkplug.  Although the gasoline / air mix *can* detonate, it will be less harmful to the gun parts and produce a more reliable amount of thrust if it deflagrates instead.

If you have no sparkplug, and instead rely on spontaneous combustion due to compression ignition, the timing of the ignition will depend on the temperatures of the air, the piston, the walls of the firing chamber, etc.

Seventh, a gas spring instead of a steel spring.  Optional.

Eighth, some repeating mechanism.  Optional.

A gasoline fueled gun will have more in common with a gasoline two stroke engine than with any real world gun or air gun.

That's not a bad thing, but it means that you might want to talk with gear heads instead of gun nuts for insight.

Also, notice the ammunition would be shell-less, which means that the you can omit the typical shell ejection mechanisms which gunpowder firearms have.

It's even primer-less, and considering what's in gun primer, that's a great thing.